# Center img on viewport width not working?

Tags: css, flexbox

Currently, I have text next to an image. I want it to move to where the text is below the image, and the image is centered when the viewport is less than 500px.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=".col-xs-6 .col-md-4" id="whoBox" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
      <div id="whoPic">
          <img src="myImgUrl">
      </div>
      <div class="wordBlock">
          <p>lorem ipsum</p>
          <p>lorem ipsum</p>
          <p>lorem ipsum</p>
          <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .wordBlock {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    div.row #whoPic {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }
    .whoBox {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've been trying flexbox, `text-align`, etc. I've tried `margin: auto;` as well. I've tried it calling all `img`, the image's ID `#whoPic`, and I've tried calling the div ID `#whoBox`.

It does work when modifying the original CSS that's not inside the @media rule.

**EDIT**: Here's what worked. I could have sworn that I tried this before posting my question, but it must have been on something else.

```
div.row #whoPic {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using diplay flex, and display block in same div , remove display block from #whoPic

```
div.row #whoPic {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: @David Risa__B is correct, also you can remove margin: 0 auto

Comment: Here's what ended up working. I could have sworn I tried it, but it must have been on a different class that I tried it on. 

    div.row #whoPic {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;

Comment: Ohhh okay i understand , you was given float to #whoPic and to .wordBlock too

Answer (score 0):

add this class to your img tag.

class="img-responsive"

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do without flex properties 
Just add this

```
div.row #whoPic img { 
        display:block;
        margin:auto;   }
   }
```